# Error al no dejar ingresar letras en un campo con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema con mi función , estoy validando que no se puedan ingresar letras en el campo la función funciona pero a medias, cuando dejo de escribir me deja la ultima letra este es mi código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi función

```
 validarNumeros() {
    const patt = new RegExp('/^[ 0-9áéíóúüñ]*$/');
    const pattReplace = new RegExp('[^ 0-9áéíóúüñ]+');
    $('#NumeroUno').on('input', function (e) {
      if (!patt.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(pattReplace, '');
      }
    });
  }
```

Este es mi `html`:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="descripcionNumero">
    <label class="">Número</label>
    <span class="textBigRed">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NumeroUno" formControlName="NumeroUno"
     (blur)="ConcatenarDireccion('num',contactoFrom.controls.NumeroUno.value)" 
     (input)="validarNumeros()" [attr.disabled]="formBuscarLocked" />

    </div>
```

Así concateno:

```
 ConcatenarDireccion(campo, formCampo) {
 if (campo === 'via') {
   this.Via = formCampo.Abreviatura;
  } else if (campo === 'num') {
   this.Numero = formCampo;
  } else if (campo === 'letra') {
   this.Letra = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (campo === 'numDos') {
   this.NumeroDos = formCampo;
  } else if (campo === 'letraDos') {
   this.LetraDos = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (campo === 'card') {
   this.Cardinal = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (campo === 'numTres') {
   this.NumeroTres = formCampo;
  } else if (campo === 'inmu') {
   this.inmueble = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (campo === 'numCuatro') {
   this.NumeroCuatro = formCampo;
  }
}
```

y así lo muestro:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" [hidden]="ocultarDireccion">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
        <label class="textBlod"> Direccion seleccionada: &nbsp; </label>
           <span>
                {{Via}} {{Numero}} {{Letra}} {{NumeroDos}} {{LetraDos}} {{Cardinal}} {{NumeroTres}} {{inmueble}}
                 {{NumeroCuatro}}
             </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Que estoy haciendo mal ? o hay otra forma de hacerlo ?

Comment: Deberias agregar la funcion `ConcatenarDireccion`

Comment: Cuando concatene validar que no se ingresen letras ?

Comment: No, que edites tu pregunta agregando la funcion para poder ver porque se concatena ese valor.

Comment: Listo @alanfcm, ya agregue la función y como lo muestro

Comment: Tiene alguna solución ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas lo que sucede es que alteras el valor del input mas no lo vuelves a actualizar en span.

```
validarNumeros() {
    const patt = new RegExp('/^[ 0-9áéíóúüñ]*$/');
    const pattReplace = new RegExp('[^ 0-9áéíóúüñ]+');
    $('#NumeroUno').on('input', function (e) {
      if (!patt.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(pattReplace, '');
        ConcatenarDireccion('num',this.value);
      }
    });
  }
```

Aqui te agrego que vuelva a concatenar.

Comment: Voy a realizar el cambio y a probar y te aviso gracias!

Comment: Me aparece este error `No se encuentra el nombre 'ConcatenarDireccion'.` cuando agrego la función concatenar a esa función, si le pongo `this.` funciona pero al escribir me aparece el mismo error pero en consola `ERROR TypeError: this.ConcatenarDireccion is not a function`

Comment: Quite la funcion y deje que solo remplazara la variable `else if (campo === 'num') {
   this.Numero = formCampo;
  }`  `this.Numero` pero sigue concatenando la ultima letra que presiono

Comment: La función está en el mismo documento?

Comment: si @oegpyg esta en el mismo documento

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96496/sala-de-ayuda-programacion a sala de chat y te ayudo

Answer (score 0):

Bueno le di solucion de esta forma , tenia dos problemas uno deba cambiar el tipo de evento en el boton de `(input)` a `(keypress)` asi:

```
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="descripcionNumero">
        <label class="">Número</label>
        <span class="textBigRed">*</span>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NumeroUno" formControlName="NumeroUno"
         (blur)="ConcatenarDireccion('num',contactoFrom.controls.NumeroUno.value)" (keypress)="validarNumeros()" 
[attr.disabled]="formBuscarLocked" />

    </div>
```

Y en mi component  modifique la función que convierte y la puse a retornar `string` modificando la variable directamente así :

```
funcionConvert(campo): string {
    const patt = new RegExp('/^[ 0-9áéíóúüñ]*$/');
    const pattReplace = new RegExp('[^ 0-9áéíóúüñ]+');
    if (!patt.test(campo)) {
      campo = campo.replace(pattReplace, '');
      return campo;
    }
  }
```

Método que concatena:

```
 ConcatenarDireccion(campo, formCampo) {
    if (campo === 'via') {
      this.Via = formCampo.Abreviatura;
    } else if (campo === 'num') { //
      this.Numero = this.funcionConvert(formCampo);
    } else if (campo === 'letra') {
      this.Letra = formCampo.Descripcion;
    } else if (campo === 'numDos') { //
      this.NumeroDos = this.funcionConvert(formCampo);
    } else if (campo === 'letraDos') {
      this.LetraDos = formCampo.Descripcion;
    } else if (campo === 'card') {
      this.Cardinal = formCampo.Descripcion;
    } else if (campo === 'numTres') { //
      this.NumeroTres = this.funcionConvert(formCampo);
    } else if (campo === 'inmu') {
      this.inmueble = formCampo.Descripcion;
    } else if (campo === 'numCuatro') {
      this.NumeroCuatro = this.funcionConvert(formCampo);
    }
  }
```